# UnboundLocalError: local variable '2darray1' referenced before assignment [Python]

Tags: python, error-handling, global-variables

```
2darray1 = 2D array with different values which are used later
2darray2 = 2D array which is empty, and values are added later
backup = 2darray1, used if the user changes one of the values, but wants to go back
Totals = empty, normal array which will have values added later

(Function which contains rest of the code, the user changing and adding values in the arrays)
```

I know i have to use globals in order to make the code not output the error, but I don't know how to use them in this context or maybe there is a better way of fixing it. I will really appreciate if any of you guys here could help me out. If you need the whole code, i can send you images on email, because it is quite lengthy.

Comment: Whittle your code down to the smallest code that exhibits the problem, then post that (in your question, as text, not as an image, and not by e-mail...)

Comment: As it stands, there is insufficient information to point to a specific error. However, providing the whole code would also not be appropriate. Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).